# How do I log an error thrown by the metamask browser extension?

Tags: javascript, solidity, metamask

I'm trying to catch an error on Metamask before having to pay gas fees for the transaction and have the error message come to me. When the wallet pops up, the following error is displayed in the console but I'm not able to catch it anywhere. [Here's a screenshot of what's popping up in the browser console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI9T5.png)

Would love some clarity on the same, thanks.

Comment: Are you using testnet ? if yes then which one ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.